# Inconsistent behaviour in SSH server for remote connections

Tags: ssh

I forwarded the port 22 and sent my WAN IP to two friends outside my local network, one of them using ubuntu and other win10. They had no problem in connecting to my machine using SSH.

Right after that I sent my WAN IP to two of my coworkers and they had timed out when tried to connect to my machine using SSH. I them tried an SSH server testing service like https://infobyip.com/sshservertest.php and it couldn't connect as well while the former 2 friend can connect.

In the end, the same command `ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works for my two friends using ubuntu and win10, and didn't work to my two coworkers using ubuntu and win10 as well. The only difference between these peoples are the location: my two friends are from my city and the two coworkers are from another city. Could it be the reason they and the [infobyip](https://infobyip.com/sshservertest.php) website can't connect to my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have a public WAN IP? Where I live some providers put you in what you can imagine as a big LAN, so your external router IP is not really WAN-public, and only other customers of that provider will be able to connect to you.

Are your friends served by the same provider? This might explain the strange behaviour.

**EDIT - Possible solutions:**

- call your provider and ask for a real public ip, some gives you this
  possibility (it might not be free)
- reverse the connection so that it's you opening it, you may want to
  look at ssh reverse tunnelling (this makes sense if you know in
  advance who will need to connect to you, and if they don't have the
  same "problem" you have)
- use services like ngrok that allow you to "expose" a service on the
  internet, you basically connect to ngrok (since the connection is
  from you to them there's no problem) and then others can connect to
  your ngrok-exposed-service and get proxyed to you (ngrok has a free
  version with some limitation, you can give it a try)

Comment: yeah, that is actually the problem.  
If I am "trapped" in this ISP can I still be able to get connections from outside this provider?

Comment: @FelipeLincoln i've edited the answer with possible solutions

Comment: I just find out my provider put me on a CGNAT, this explain the behaviour. I just contacted them and ask if I could opt out CGNAT, and they put me out. Now I get a real WAN public IP. I also tried ngrok and found it amazing, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The different city should not be a problem, at all.

Maybe your coworkers have a very restrictive internet provider filtering SSH connections.
Maybe your WAN IP changed in the meanwhile.
Maybe your LAN IP changed (so that the port forwarding does not work anymore) and you need to set it fixed.

Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  
My WAN and LAN are still the same. Have any idea why websites that check ssh connection can't connect to my ssh as well?

Comment: No, the whole story is too strange, something has to be wrong. Are the two friends still able to connect? Can the two coworkers connect to any other SSH server anywhere?